# Guizero's TextBox.value stops updating after pyplot.figure() is called

Tags: python

I want to create simple GUI using guizero library, but I found out that TextBox.value stops updating when matplotlib.pyplot.figure() is called.

I have not tried almost anything since I have no idea how to solve it. I just found the problem.

```
from guizero import App, TextBox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

def print_value():
    print(text_box.value)

app = App()

text_box = TextBox(app, command=print_value)

app.display()
```

I want to use TextBox as input for values (floats). If the plt.figure() is not in the code, I just enter the value in the UI and by calling text_box.value I can read the value (and print it immediately as in the example). However, I also want to use matplotlib.pyplot to plot the data. The problem is when the plt.figure() is in the code the text_box.value stops being updated. I can enter whatever I want in the UI but the text_box.value remains unchanged (it is either empty string as in this case or just default string value if I define it). Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is it a bug?